# How to explain PHPDoc attributes of `@property-read` and `@property-write`?

Tags: php, phpdoc

Given the [phpDoc manual](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/), I cannot find explanation about that

- `@property-read`
- `@property-write`

but only of `@property`.

What do they do?

Comment: See: https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's a good explanation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) on magic properties.

Basically, `@property-write` is interpreted - as the name suggests - as a write-only property. The code completion in Eclipse, for example, makes use of this. If your magic property `foo` is declared "write-only", it wouldn't show up in code completion, when you type `$a = $this->f`.

Comment: yes i already read that page, but it still not clear for me what is `@property-read` and `@property-write`

Answer (score 6):

The @property tag is what's documented in the phpDocumentor manual.  This tag is used only in a class docblock to document a "magic" property/variable, i.e. one that is not defined in the code, and therefore can't be "docblock'd".

Now, when you want to highlight that a particular "magic variable" is read-only (not writable), you'd use @property-read.  If you have a "magic variable" that is write-only (not readable), you'd use @property-write.  Granted, I have trouble imagining write-only variables that can't be read, but since it's technically possible to do it, @property-write is available for you to document it.

These two "subtags" of @property are explained farther down on the @property page that you linked to above.

Answer (score 1):

`@property-read` tells the IDE (and doc generator) that a magic **G**et-only field exists.

`@property-write` tells the IDE that a magic **S**et-only field exists.

PHP 8.1 added `readonly` keyword,
which basically forbids setting a variable to another value (except initial value).